# how can i create 2 dynamic dropdown from one table in database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

Can someone help me on how to link up 2 dropdown list which data came from the same table in the database, is it possible to do this way because I can only find a solution which there must be 2 table in the database to link up those two. this is how should it work, 1st, the user choose the department and the 2nd dropdown will show only the people that assigned from that particular department.

database table has id,name,department.

the department works already but the 2nd dropdown didnt work to filter from the department. Can someone help me to know what is wrong with this?

index.php

```html
<?php
$query ="SELECT DISTINCT company from hrar";
$results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?>
<script>
function getName(val) {
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "getName.php",
 data:'department='+val,
 success: function(data){
  $("#nameList").html(data);
 }
 });
}

function selectDepartment(val) {
$("#search-box").val(val);
$("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
</script>

<label>Department:</label><br/>
<select name="country" id="country-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getName(this.value);">
<option value="">Select Department</option>
<?php
foreach($results as $country) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["company"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>Name:</label><br/>
<select name="state" id="nameList" class="demoInputBox">
<option value="">Select Name</option>
</select>

//below is the getName.php

if(!empty($_POST["company"])) {
 $query ="SELECT DISTINCT name from hrar = '" . $_POST["company"] . "'";
 $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?>
 <option value="">Select Name</option>
<?php
 foreach($results as $name) {
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $name["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $name["name"]; ?></option>
<?php
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Vars should not start with uppercase as $Search. I know you can do it but it's not a good practice.

Comment: What you are asking for can be done in different ways but the one I think it's better is to perform an ajax call to get the values of the second select when the firts one value is changed. jQuery can help you with the ajax call.

Comment: The logic is the same as in the examples you found for 2 tables. Just select from the same table the 2nd time as well.

Comment: @Shadow i did, i tried many ways to code that but it just wont work, thats when i thought because of key linked in the dtabase table maybe as other example..im not so sure though..im stuck bcause i dont really know how to code in jQuery and ajax so much even after i tried that

Comment: @jeprubio thanks for the adviced, im stuck bcause i dont really know how to code in jQuery and ajax so much, someone can help me show the way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<select name="filter" id="filter" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="name">Select Name</option>
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM hr";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<option value='". $row['name'] ."'>" .$row['name'] ."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```